# Win 10 locations services locked to off -- how can I unlock them?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, geolocation, security-policy, location-services

I have a personal Thinkpad P1 running Windows 10 Pro (version 1909, build 18363.535).  I would like to turn on Location Services so that I can turn on Find My Device.

However, when I go to Settings>Privacy>Location the *Allow access to location on this device* setting is off and the *Change* button is disabled, with the `*Some settings are managed by an administrator` text being displayed.

This is my computer and I am the only administrator.  I don't recall setting a group policy or anything like that to disable the option.  However, I have checked in both the Group Policy editor and the Security Policy editor and cannot find any place where I could have changed something (everything is set to `Not Configured`).

I also tried running "O&O Shut Up" and it does not show any location-related thing (including Windows Geolocation Service) being disabled.  That said, when I do look at the *Services* app I do not see any listed services that appear to be about location.

I'm at a loss for what to look for next or how to enable the ability to turn location access on the device off and on rather than having it be locked off.

Comment: Scroll down the list in this setting.  Try setting to Default Location and under that Clear Location History on this device

Comment: Most Settings like this will display this message when a required related setting is disabled.  The use of the third-party program is likely to blame.